# Splitting a row based on a condition

Tags: sql-server, split, sql-server-2008-r2, rows

i have a scenario. In a table i got 2 fields which checks for a patients. For example, if a patient has 'A' or if a patient has 'B'.

But when i pull the record, i want 2 records, one for A and one for B. I know this could be done using UNION ALL but is there a different way to do that because UNION ALL will be way too bulky code for me. Please help!

Example would be like this.

In Table Patients

```
PatientID Name         Age HasA HasB
1234      Sad          18  Yes  Yes
4567      Happy        40  Yes  No
8901      confused     25   No  Yes
```

so my query should return:

```
PatientID Name         Age Has
1234      Sad          18  A 
1234      Sad          18   B
4567      Happy        40  A
8901      confused     25   B
```

so a sort of duplicate row if it has both A and B.

Answer (score 0):

Although I would assume `union all` would perform better, but at least this is one way to do it:

```
select PatientID, Name, Age, t2.Code as Has 
from Table1 t1
left outer join Table2 t2 on 
  ((t2.Code = 'A' and t2.Yes = T1.HasA) or 
  (t2.Code = 'B' and t2.Yes = T1.HasB))
```

Example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ed13c/1)

Table2 is just a simple table that has A, Yes and B, Yes rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try.

[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/48f27/3)

```
  select PatientId,Name,
  (case
  when HasA='Yes' Then 'A'
  End) as Has
  from Table1 where HasA='Yes'
  Union All
  select PatientId,Name,
  (case
  when HasB='Yes' Then 'B'
  End) as Has
  from Table1 where HasB='Yes'
```